# Invalid client_id when using the linkedin-api-php-client library by zoonman

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm using this api client library for php and I get the next error all the time when making the first Oauth2 redirection to get the GET(code) first token:

> The passed in client_id is invalid

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there was en error while creating the client id string from the .env hidden file. It was generating by adding a return carriage ascii code at the end, due was read by file() php function that by default, includes the EOL characters at the end of each returned array line.